# Numpy - Filtering The Array Based on Indices and Respecting Axis

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have an integer `ids` array and a float `distances_per_batch` array:

```
BATCH_SIZE = 500
ARRAY_SIZE = 10000

ids = np.arange(ARRAY_SIZE) # Shape = ARRAY_SIZE,
distances_per_batch = np.random.rand(BATCH_SIZE, ARRAY_SIZE) # Shape = BATCH_SIZE, ARRAY_SIZE
```

I'm trying to get the ids where their distance is higher than 0.9:

```
ids_expanded = np.repeat(np.expand_dims(ids, axis=0), BATCH_SIZE, axis=0) # Shape = BATCH_SIZE, ARRAY_SIZE (Not sure if this is even right to use since it takes a while for larger BATCH_SIZE & ARRAY_SIZE and seems to create a new array
selected_ids = ids_expanded[distances_per_batch > 0.9]
```

I'm expecting `selected_ids` to have a 2-Dimensional shape of `(500,?)` to get the ids which have a distance greater than 0.9 for each entry in the batch (total 500 entries) but the final result is automatically reshaped to a 1-Dimensional array and I can't decide which selected id belongs to which of the 500 entries...

How can I get the desired results in a fast and proper way (not looping through every record one by one and using Numpy's faster methods)? I'm not even sure if expanding dimensions and repeating the array is the proper way since it takes a while for larger BATCH_SIZE & ARRAY_SIZE and seems to create a new array.

Comment: Are you trying to get the indices for which distance > 0.9?

Comment: @SatheeshK I'm Trying To Get The IDs for which distance > 0.9 (And I end up getting them) but I get them in flat 1-Dimensional array And I lose the axis from which they were calculated... I want a 2-Dimensional array...

Answer (score 1):

```
np.where(distances_per_batch > 0.9)
```

returns separate arrays of rows and columns indexes. To gather them

```
np.transpose(np.where(distances_per_batch > 0.9))
```

with any random data it returns

```
array([[   0,    0],
       [   0,   31],
       [   0,   33],
       ..., 
       [ 499, 9988],
       [ 499, 9993],
       [ 499, 9995]], dtype=int32)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but how can I use this for filtering out the `ids` array?

Comment: `ids[np.where(distances_per_batch > 0.9)]`

Comment: Thanks but `ids[np.where(distances_per_batch > 0.9)]` doesn't work and we get an error: `{IndexError}too many indices for array`.

Comment: Ok. set `BATCH_SIZE = 5, ARRAY_SIZE = 10` and show the source arrays and the desired result

Comment: Thanks. Here's a link to the PyCharm's Debugger containing both `ids` and `distances_per_batch` values: https://i.imgur.com/LlyuXqK.png

Comment: I don't understand what to do with that image.I guess you want to get positions in distances_per_batch where item > 0.9 ? np.where(distances_per_batch > 0.9) give you such rows and cols. What do you want to filter more?

Comment: The first step is to get positions in `distances_per_batch` but then I want to get the corresponding ids to these positions. If i was doing this without considering batches of data and processing distances one by one then your suggestion would work but since we have batches of data, a simple `ids[distances_per_batch > 0.9]` or `ids[np.where(distances_per_batch > 0.9)]` would not work since `ids` is one dimensional but `distances_per_batch > 0.9` is two dimensional and those codes would end up with the `{IndexError}too many indices for array` error.

Comment: ids = [[1,2,3]] np.where(distances_per_batch > 0.9) = ([[1,3]],[[0,4]]) ?  What *the corresponding ids to these positions* ?

Comment: Here's a gist that wouldn't work with this approach: https://gist.github.com/Neltherion/4c15d29584a51d1070bce77a37c986f8

Comment: I try to understand your logic, not how you write the code.  *The first step is to get positions in distances_per_batch but then I want to get the corresponding ids* What the rule to get **corresponding ids** ?

Comment: Here's the scenario: You have a couple of `ids` (e.g 10000 ids) and you have a couple of `features` for each id (e.g 10000 features). Then you calculate the distance between each feature and the rest of the features batch by batch (e.g. batches of 500) which would get you a list of `distances_per_batch` in the shape of 500x10000 (500 distances from 500 features to the rest of 10000 features). The first 500 `ids` correspond to the first 500 distances of `distances_per_batch`. I tried to omit how the `distances_per_batch` array is created which seems to have backfired!

Comment: `np.where(distances_per_batch > 0.9)[0]`